# How can I pass information from an item to a Modal in django to edit it?

Tags: python, django, popup

I have a template where I'm showing with a 'for' my elements, and those elements have a Edit button, so what I want to do, is when the user clicks edit, a pop up appears with the form and the information of that item.
So I don't know how to do that:(

Answer (score 0):

so if you are using Javascript in your template then you can get the row index of clicked button and then get information from there and bind it to your popup.